# Is it possible to maintain the fillcolor when the y-axis is reversed?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line graph that uses a fillColor / linearGradient.  When I reverse the y-axis, the fill moves to be from the line up to the top of the graph.  I want it to stay as the fill from the line down to the x-axis.

For example:

http://highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-reversed

Notice that the blue fill is above the line when the Y-axis is reversed.  I want it to remain below the line even when I reverse the axis.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle or some code. Your description is not very clear.

Comment: Done.  Let me know if this is clear.

Comment: Okay...odd. Well the gradient fill is defined as being from the 0 y-point up to the maximum y-point along the x-axis (hence it is called a "fill"). Since you are reversing where the y-Axis is it still has to fill the space between the line and the x-axis so the gradient is moved to be above the line. Things to consider: Why are you flipping y-axis (not saying it is wrong but is it necessary). Why not set a fill color of solid white and a background fill of gradient?

Comment: Good question.  The value I'm graphing can be interpreted in different ways depending on the user.  For some, a low number is good.  For others, it is bad.  So, the ability to reverse the axis is on screen for each user.  I will try your suggestion, it makes sense albeit a bit of a hassle.  I'm going to start with a background of white and a blue gradient, then just swap them when the axis is reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/4tTWH/1/) is a simple example as explained in my comment. I hope this helps.

This is the important part:

```
    chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            ...
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgb(69, 114, 167)'],
                        [1, 'rgba(2,0,0,0)']
                    ]
            },
        },
...
    plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    fillColor: 'white'
                }
            },
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but is it possible to keep the x-axis grid lines intact also?  I'd want to show them on the top, but not the bottom.  Sorry to be picky, but I know that would be requested.

Comment: Hrm. This is odd. fillOpacity is having no effect if you set the fillColor. This may be a bug. Or I may be missing something simple.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing an easy way to do it.  Granted, your way works but I wish I could fix the grid lines.  If you somehow stumble across it, please let me know.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sma you can use CSS3 to get the fill opacity to work set the fill opacity to fillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)', use any css3 color generator to pick a color. I'd also like a built in method to flip my y axis and fill the bottom of it.